# как поставить картинке position: sticky;?

Tags: html, css

Есть код, и надо к картинкам добавить `position: sticky;`, возможно ли это сделать? У меня лично не получается

html-код

```
<div style="position: sticky;"><img src="img/cats-32.jpg" class="infimg">
```

```css
.infimg {
 height: 130px;
 width: 230px;
 text-align: left;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 900px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: sticky;
}

.infimg:hover{
 filter: blur(2px); -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
 position: sticky;
}

.infimginf {
 height: 130px;
 width: 230px;
    text-align: right;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding-left: 10px;
 position: sticky;
}

.infimginf:hover {
 filter: blur(2px); -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
 position: sticky;
}
```

Если есть варианты, то пишите. (Браузер Google Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.infimg {
 height: 130px;
 width: 230px;
 text-align: left;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 200px; /*Для примера уменьшил с 900 */
 cursor: pointer;
  border:1px solid red
}

.infimg:hover{
 filter: blur(2px); -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}

.infimginf {
 height: 130px;
 width: 230px;
    text-align: right;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding-left: 10px;
   border:1px solid green
}

.infimginf:hover {
 filter: blur(2px); -webkit-filter: blur(2px)
}
```

```html
    <p>Istam voluptatem perpetuam quis potest praestare sapienti? Quod non faceret, si in voluptate summum bonum poneret. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti; Sed nimis multa. </p>

    <p>Hic ambiguo ludimur. Certe, nisi voluptatem tanti aestimaretis. Non igitur bene. Dempta enim aeternitate nihilo beatior Iuppiter quam Epicurus; </p>

    <p>Laboro autem non sine causa; Omnia peccata paria dicitis. Aufert enim sensus actionemque tollit omnem. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. </p>

    <div style="
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      background-color: yellow;
      padding: 50px;
      font-size: 20px;">
      <img src="img/cats-32.jpg" class="infimg" alt="КАРТИНКА">
    </div>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quid dubitas igitur mutare principia naturae? Equidem e Cn. Quae sequuntur igitur? Quantum Aristoxeni ingenium consumptum videmus in musicis? </p>

    <p>Teneo, inquit, finem illi videri nihil dolere. Si enim ad populum me vocas, eum. Sed nimis multa. Quis hoc dicit? Graece donan, Latine voluptatem vocant. Dici enim nihil potest verius. </p>

    <div style="
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      background-color: #F984EF;
      padding: 50px;
      font-size: 20px;">
      <img src="img/cats-321.jpg" class="infimginf" alt="КАРТИНКА 2">
    </div>


    <p>Istam voluptatem perpetuam quis potest praestare sapienti? Quod non faceret, si in voluptate summum bonum poneret. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti; Sed nimis multa. </p>

    <p>Hic ambiguo ludimur. Certe, nisi voluptatem tanti aestimaretis. Non igitur bene. Dempta enim aeternitate nihilo beatior Iuppiter quam Epicurus; </p>

    <p>Laboro autem non sine causa; Omnia peccata paria dicitis. Aufert enim sensus actionemque tollit omnem. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quid dubitas igitur mutare principia naturae? Equidem e Cn. Quae sequuntur igitur? Quantum Aristoxeni ingenium consumptum videmus in musicis? </p>

    <p>Teneo, inquit, finem illi videri nihil dolere. Si enim ad populum me vocas, eum. Sed nimis multa. Quis hoc dicit? Graece donan, Latine voluptatem vocant. Dici enim nihil potest verius. </p>

    <p>Istam voluptatem perpetuam quis potest praestare sapienti? Quod non faceret, si in voluptate summum bonum poneret. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti; Sed nimis multa. </p>

    <p>Hic ambiguo ludimur. Certe, nisi voluptatem tanti aestimaretis. Non igitur bene. Dempta enim aeternitate nihilo beatior Iuppiter quam Epicurus; </p>

    <p>Laboro autem non sine causa; Omnia peccata paria dicitis. Aufert enim sensus actionemque tollit omnem. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quid dubitas igitur mutare principia naturae? Equidem e Cn. Quae sequuntur igitur? Quantum Aristoxeni ingenium consumptum videmus in musicis? </p>

    <p>Teneo, inquit, finem illi videri nihil dolere. Si enim ad populum me vocas, eum. Sed nimis multa. Quis hoc dicit? Graece donan, Latine voluptatem vocant. Dici enim nihil potest verius. </p>

    <p>Istam voluptatem perpetuam quis potest praestare sapienti? Quod non faceret, si in voluptate summum bonum poneret. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti; Sed nimis multa. </p>

    <p>Hic ambiguo ludimur. Certe, nisi voluptatem tanti aestimaretis. Non igitur bene. Dempta enim aeternitate nihilo beatior Iuppiter quam Epicurus; </p>

    <p>Laboro autem non sine causa; Omnia peccata paria dicitis. Aufert enim sensus actionemque tollit omnem. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. </p>
```